# Can ''anecdote'' be synonymous with ''detail'' or ''small point''?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, synonyms

As in, would it be correct to write something like:

> It is simply ***anecdotal*** that I didn't finish college?

Further, can it be used in this sense in the form of a question? E.g.,

> This is only an ***anecdote***, but what are Harry's parents' names?

Comment: [Incidental](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incidental) might fit your first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

An [anecdote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anecdote) is a "story with a point". There should be a story, and that story should be illustrating something about a person, object, place or situation.

It is not synonymous with "detail" or "small point". These are different concepts.

It might be anecdotal that you didn't finish college if you were making a point about yourself or college, but "What are Harry's parents' names" is a question. There's no story, and no obvious point being made.

["Anecdotal" is the adjective of the noun "anecdote". I'm not aware of any verb forms that wouldn't sound like I was trying too hard to find one (eg. "anecdotify").]

Answer (score 0):

There is a connotation of the noun *anecdote* that might make you think it is appropriate for your context, but it is not your best choice.

Among the definitions of [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=anecdote%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsY48QqXT-ZOdxe2AdStwurmv-2XTA%3A1659466849054&ei=YXTpYsjfAoeVgQak879Q&ved=0ahUKEwiIlLfg66j5AhWHSsAKHaT5DwoQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=anecdote%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyDQgAEIAEELEDEEYQ-QEyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BAgAEEM6BwgAELEDEENKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ5RNY1iBghCZoAXABeACAAWaIAbQFkgEDNy4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) there is one that says

> an account regarded as ***unreliable*** or ***hearsay***.
>
> - His wife's death has long been the subject of rumour and ***anecdote***.

In your context, however, you do not need a noun or adjective referring to an unreliable fact. What you need, is the notion of ***side fact*** or, as it has been indicated in the comments, something ***incidental***, ***of no consequence***, ***[tangential](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangential)***.

Answer (score 0):

Your title question is asking about the meanings and associations and correlations of the terms  'anecdote', 'detail', and 'small point'.

An anecdote is a very short description of an event.

A detail is a very small factor of an object or situation.

A small point is point that is, well, small.

An anecdote is a story, a detail is usually a feature (but one feature of a longer story may be a small inconsequential story that is anecdotal in nature), and a small point is a point, that is a thing of special significance, which is small.

Yes, all of these have something 'small' about a description within them. But they are fairly distinct enough that they wouldn't be called synonyms of each other (a detail and small point are almost synonymous).

But it turns out that what you want to do with these words is really more answered by knowing what 'synonym' means.
['Synonym' means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synonym)

> 1: one of two or more words or expressions of the same language that have the same or nearly the same meaning in some or all senses

The important part is "same or nearly the same meaning". Often people say that a synonym is something that can replace another.

But replacement does not mean synonymous. You might want to say:

> Carbon sequestration **ameliorates** global warming.

where it improves the conditions of global warming.

Or

> Carbon sequestration **mitigates** global warming.

where it reduces the bad outcomes. You might infer that a reduction in bad a outcomes is an improvement in conditions, but those are not the same thing.

These two words mean two distinct (but yes very close meanings). They might well be placed next to each other in a thesaurus, and often when writing you may want to replace one with the other, but they have different implications.

In the end though, 'anecdote', while it -is- often a detail or small point, is neither a synonym of 'detail' or 'small point'  and by meaning, can't really replace either in all situations. An example of an anecdote may well be small detail, but there are quite a few other kinds of small points. For example, the color of a shirt in a photograph is a detail, but it really does not make up an entire anecdote.